# Describing a nested object for typescript .d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces, declare, .d.ts

In my project, I'm importing an object. That object is created by a function so the IDE has no clue what keys are on it (they're dynamic based on the config provided). My thought is that I can generate a `.d.ts` file that describes the object so people looking to know what keys are on it, can find them with code completion in the IDE.

```js
// dynamicObject.js
export default makeAnObject(config);
```

```js
// useObject.js
import someObject from './dynamicObject.js';

const result = someObject.| (code editor dropdown of keys here)
```

On one other note, I'm interested in **not** having the `.d.ts` file in the same directory as these files. I assume the `tsconfig.json` can handle this, I just have no clue what the syntax for the `.d.ts` file would look like. Typescript is hugely foreign to me and the docs are not helpful.

For my `dynamicObject.d.ts` file, I started with something like this

```
declare namespace someObject {
   interface oneKey {
      nestedKey: string
   }
}
```

But the code editor still has no clue what the object composition is. I'm not sure if it's the way I'm writing the `.d.ts` file or something I'm missing in the `tsconfig.json`?

**EDIT**: Going to include my `tsconfig.json` as the first answer didn't work. Looking to have the most basic config, but I can imagine it might be missing more:

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions" : {
       "baseUrl": "./",
       "paths": {
           "*" : ["myCustomTypings/**.d.ts"]
       }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2** I've temporarily moved the `.d.ts` file in the same directory as the `dynamicObject.js` (named `dynamicObject.d.ts`) and now the IDE can tell it's `typeof someObject` but can't tell the object's structure. How do I describe the object in `dynamicObject.d.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

It's need to declare typeRoots in tsconfig.json.

Below is example

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "typeRoots" : [ "./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I included my current config (which itself also doesn't seem to do anything) and from what I've read quickly `typeRoots` isn't often used and hidden in the docs for reasons I don't entirely understand. Everyone is then pointed to using `baseUrl` and `paths`.

Comment: I think I know why it doesn't work. I believe `typeRoots` is for named modules in the project. This is just importing a relative path in the project. I'm under the impression I should be using the `baseUrl` and `paths` keys, but something else must be wrong.